# (Swift) UITableView - Attempt to move index path to index path that does not exist

Tags: swift, uitableview, indexpath

I have a UITableView consisting of 2 sections. Rows are initially printed in section 0. They must be moveable between sections.

When I move a cell from section 0 to section 1, I get:

```
"Attempt to move index path to index path that does not exist"
```

Here is my code.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.tableView.moveRowAtIndexPath(sourceIndexPath, toIndexPath: destinationIndexPath)
}
```

These all return the correct values:

```
print("source row \(sourceIndexPath.row)")
print("source section \(sourceIndexPath.section)")
print("destination row \(destinationIndexPath.row)")
print("destination section \(destinationIndexPath.section)")
```

Any ideas on how I can solve this?

Update:

I've looked into the fetchedResultsControllerDelegate and now I have this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let movedObject = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(sourceIndexPath) as! NSManagedObject
    print(movedObject)

     controller(self.fetchedResultsController, didChangeObject: movedObject, atIndexPath: sourceIndexPath, forChangeType: NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Delete, newIndexPath: destinationIndexPath)

     self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([sourceIndexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)

     controller(self.fetchedResultsController, didChangeObject: movedObject, atIndexPath: sourceIndexPath, forChangeType: NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Insert, newIndexPath: destinationIndexPath)

     self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([destinationIndexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
}
```

Now the error is invalid update:

Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

I'm doing a delete then insert, so technically the number of rows should still be the same.

Comment: You have to update your model

Comment: How would I go about that?

Comment: check answer below

Answer (score 2):

Update model in your `datasource` *is your array that fill data to table*  then use  `moveRowAtIndexPath`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {

            let movedObject = self.datasource[sourceIndexPath.row]
            datasource.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
            datasource.insert(movedObject, at: destinationIndexPath.row)

            self.tableView.moveRowAtIndexPath(sourceIndexPath, toIndexPath: destinationIndexPath)


        }
```

don't forget enable moving

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {

    return true
}
```

Comment: How would I remove and insert from FetchedResultsController?

Comment: To Work with  `FetchedResultsController `  you can use this example for more details 
https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/05/28/sync-table-view-data-nsfetchedresultscontroller-swift/

Comment: and source code example https://github.com/andrewcbancroft/Zootastic/tree/NSFetchedResultsController_SyncTableView

Comment: I'm still having some trouble. I've updated my question.

Comment: what is your problem

Comment: insert and delete results in an invalid number of rows.