# Crash: Attempt to move index path to index path that does not exist

Tags: swift, uitableview

Someone asked about this error before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50362624/swift-uitableview-attempt-to-move-index-path-to-index-path-that-does-not-exi) but he was not updating his model and to my knowledge that is all I am doing and then refreshing the tableView so I wanted to see if anyone has any thoughts on this. I would really appreciate any advice, since I can't seem to get to the bottom of this and users keep reporting the issue.

The issue is:
The app crashes if a user drags a task from Overdue to any of the other sections. The error is this:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to move index
> path (<NSIndexPath: 0x9ed3b3d9edf53a85> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}) to
> index path (<NSIndexPath: 0x9ed3b3d9edf52a85> {length = 2, path = 1 -
> 0}) that does not exist - there are only 0 rows in section 1 after the
> update'

Other reports from analytics also point to this error with a similar (similarly vague that is) stack trace:

> Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of
> rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be
> equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the
> update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from
> that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of
> rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 1 moved out)

Here's my setup:
I have a tableview that displays several tasks and groups them by due date. There's a variable for the filtered array of each task, like this:

```
class ZoneController: UIViewController {
var incompleteTasks: [Task] {
    let tasks = zone.tasks.filter({ !$0.completed })
    if zone.groupTasks { return tasks.sortedByDueDate() }
    else { return tasks }
}

var overdueTasks: [Task] {
    let tasks = zone.tasks.filter({ ($0.dueDate?.isInThePast ?? false) && !$0.completed })
    if zone.groupTasks { return tasks.sortedByDueDate() }
    else { return tasks }
}

var todayTasks: [Task] {
    let tasks = zone.tasks.filter({ ($0.dueDate?.isToday ?? false) && !$0.completed && !($0.dueDate?.isInThePast ?? false) /* This is here because a task could be today but a few hours earlier, in which case it needs to be overdue */ })
    if zone.groupTasks { return tasks.sortedByDueDate() }
    else { return tasks }
}
var tomorrowTasks: [Task] {
    let tasks = zone.tasks.filter({ ($0.dueDate?.isTomorrow ?? false) && !$0.completed })
    if zone.groupTasks { return tasks.sortedByDueDate() }
    else { return tasks }
}

var laterTasks: [Task] {
    let laterTasks = zone.tasks.filter({
        var isLater = true
        if let dueDate = $0.dueDate { isLater = (dueDate > Calendar.current.dayAfterTomorrow()) }
        return !$0.completed && isLater
    })
    return laterTasks.sortedByDueDate()
}
}
```

The tableview has the option to move tasks between groups and change their due date, so in tableView moveRowAt I am switching the destinationIndexPath and changing the dueDate accordingly, then reloading the tableView. Here is the code responsible for the tableView:

```
import UIKit
import WidgetKit
import AppCenterAnalytics

extension ZoneController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if tasksTabSelected {
        if zone.groupTasks {
            switch section {
            case 0: return overdueTasks.count
            case 1: return todayTasks.count
            case 2: return tomorrowTasks.count
            default: return laterTasks.count
            }
        } else {
            return incompleteTasks.count
        }
    } else {
        return zone.ideas.count
    }
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    tasksTabSelected && zone.groupTasks ? 4 : 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    if tasksTabSelected && zone.groupTasks && !incompleteTasks.isEmpty {
        // This makes the headers scroll with the rest of the content
        let dummyViewHeight = CGFloat(44)
        tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.size.width, height: dummyViewHeight))
        tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: -dummyViewHeight, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        
        let headerTitles = ["Overdue", "Today", "Tomorrow", "Later"]
        
        let header = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TaskHeaderCell") as! TaskHeaderCell
        header.icon.image = UIImage(named: "header-\(headerTitles[section])")
        header.name.text = headerTitles[section]
        return header
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let footer = UIView()
    footer.backgroundColor = .clear
    return footer
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    var shouldBeTall = false
    
    if tasksTabSelected && zone.groupTasks {
        switch section {
        case 0: shouldBeTall = overdueTasks.count != 0
        case 1: shouldBeTall = todayTasks.count != 0
        case 2: shouldBeTall = tomorrowTasks.count != 0
        case 3: shouldBeTall = laterTasks.count != 0
        default: return 0
        }
    }
    
    return shouldBeTall ? 24 : 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    let tasksAreGrouped = tasksTabSelected && zone.groupTasks && !incompleteTasks.isEmpty
    return tasksAreGrouped && section != 0 || tasksAreGrouped && section == 0 && !overdueTasks.isEmpty ? 48 : 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if tasksTabSelected {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TaskCell") as! TaskCell
        let accentColor = UIColor(hex: zone.firstColor)
        
        var task: Task?
        
        if zone.groupTasks {
            print("Section: \(indexPath.section) has \(tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section))")
            switch indexPath.section {
            case 0: task = overdueTasks[indexPath.row]
            case 1: task = todayTasks[indexPath.row]
            case 2: task = tomorrowTasks[indexPath.row]
            case 3: task = laterTasks[indexPath.row]
            default: break
            }
        } else {
            task = incompleteTasks[indexPath.row]
        }
        
        cell.task = task
        cell.accentColor = accentColor
        cell.zoneGroupsTasks = zone.groupTasks
        
        cell.configure()
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "IdeaCell") as! IdeaCell
        let idea = zone.ideas[indexPath.row]
        cell.content.text = idea.content.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n\n\n\n", with: " ").replacingOccurrences(of: "\n\n\n", with: " ").replacingOccurrences(of: "\n\n", with: " ").replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: " ")
        cell.idea = idea
        return cell
    }
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if tasksTabSelected {
        let vc = Storyboards.main.instantiateViewController(identifier: "TaskDetails") as! TaskDetails
        vc.colors = [UIColor(hex: zone.firstColor), UIColor(hex: zone.secondColor)]
        
        if zone.groupTasks {
            switch indexPath.section {
            case 0: vc.task = overdueTasks[indexPath.row]
            case 1: vc.task = todayTasks[indexPath.row]
            case 2: vc.task = tomorrowTasks[indexPath.row]
            case 3: vc.task = laterTasks[indexPath.row]
            default: break
            }
        } else {
            vc.task = incompleteTasks[indexPath.row]
        }
        
        presentSheet(vc)
    } else {
        let vc = Storyboards.main.instantiateViewController(identifier: "IdeaDetails") as! IdeaDetails
        vc.color = UIColor(hex: zone.firstColor)
        vc.idea = zone.ideas[indexPath.row]
        presentSheet(vc)
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    if tasksTabSelected {
        if zone.groupTasks && dragSourceIndexPath?.section != destinationIndexPath.section {
            guard let dragSourceTimestamp = dragSourceTimestamp else { return }
            var task = zone.tasks.first(where: { $0.id == dragSourceTimestamp })
            task?.reminderNeeded = true
            
            switch destinationIndexPath.section {
            case 1:
                task?.dueDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 1, to: Date())
                task?.reminderNeeded = false
            case 2: task?.dueDate = Calendar.current.tomorrow(at: 9)
            case 3: task?.dueDate = Calendar.current.inTwoWeeks(at: 9)
            default: break
            }
            task?.save()
        } else {
            guard
                let sourceIndex = zone.tasks.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == incompleteTasks[sourceIndexPath.row].id }),
                let destinationIndex = zone.tasks.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == incompleteTasks[destinationIndexPath.row].id })
            else { return }
            Storage.zones[zoneIndex].tasks.move(from: sourceIndex, to: destinationIndex)
        }
    } else {
        Storage.zones[zoneIndex].ideas.move(from: sourceIndexPath.row, to: destinationIndexPath.row)
    }
    reloadTableView() // This version is being called to make sure the zone is being refreshed, even though technically tableView.reloadData() would have been enough.
    Push.updateAllReminders()
    WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()
    Analytics.trackEvent("Reordered tasks or ideas")
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, dragSessionWillBegin session: UIDragSession) {
    tableView.vibrate()
    // This is here to prevent users from dragging this task to other zones and a weird scrolling bug that happens
    if let pageController = self.parent as? PVC { pageController.decouple() }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, dragSessionDidEnd session: UIDragSession) {
    // This is here to prevent users from dragging this task to other zones and a weird scrolling bug that happens
    if let pageController = self.parent as? PVC { pageController.recouple() }
}
    
}

extension ZoneController: UITableViewDragDelegate {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {
    dragSourceIndexPath = indexPath
    dragSourceTimestamp = (tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? TaskCell)?.task.id
    return [UIDragItem(itemProvider: NSItemProvider())]
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, dragPreviewParametersForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIDragPreviewParameters? {
    let param = UIDragPreviewParameters()
    if #available(iOS 14.0, *) { param.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: .zero) }
    param.backgroundColor = .clear
    return param
}

}

extension ZoneController: UITableViewDropDelegate {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, dropSessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession, withDestinationIndexPath destinationIndexPath: IndexPath?) -> UITableViewDropProposal {

    if session.localDragSession != nil { // Drag originated from the same app.
        let isSameSection = destinationIndexPath?.section == dragSourceIndexPath?.section
        let permitted = !isSameSection && destinationIndexPath?.section != 0 || !tasksTabSelected || !zone.groupTasks
        return UITableViewDropProposal(operation: permitted ? .move : .forbidden, intent: .insertAtDestinationIndexPath)
    }

    return UITableViewDropProposal(operation: .cancel, intent: .unspecified)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, performDropWith coordinator: UITableViewDropCoordinator) {
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, dropPreviewParametersForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIDragPreviewParameters? {
    let param = UIDragPreviewParameters()
    if #available(iOS 14.0, *) { param.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: .zero) }
    param.backgroundColor = .clear
    return param
}

}
```

A few things to note:

1. The task.save() method saves the task to disk.
2. If I completely comment out the code in moveRowAt, the crash still occurs, so it is not something in there that is causing it.
3. The reloadTableView method sets an empty image if it's needed and also reads the Zone (which contains all tasks) from disk again. I am storing the Zone in memory as a variable of the ViewController for performance reasons (scrolling is very janky if I always read it from disk).

   ```
    @objc func reloadTableView() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
        zone = Storage.zones[zoneIndex]
        tableView.reloadData()
        let hidden = tasksTabSelected && incompleteTasks.isEmpty || !tasksTabSelected && zone.ideas.isEmpty
        emptyImage.isHidden = !hidden
        emptyImage.image = UIImage(named: tasksTabSelected ? "no-tasks" : "no-ideas")
    }
    }
   ```

Comment: A few things to note: Nobody knows what a guy named 'Task' or '[Task]' is.  zone.tasks?  zone.groupTasks?  Where do they come from?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @ElTomato. Yes a Zone type has a property called tasks which is an array of [Task]. So one Zone will hold all Tasks. groupTasks is a Bool property of a Zone. If a user set that to true from Settings, tasks will be grouped by their due date (which is the scenario where the crash happens). If it's set to false, tasks will just be displayed int he order they exist in the tasks array of the Zone, and there are no issues with re-ordering there because it's just a move operation (moving from one index of the tasks array of the Zone to another).

Comment: The lack of response here is probably due to the amount of code provided, which makes it too hard to get a handle on the problem.  Can you edit this down to the code relevant to the issue (eg. I don't think how you form your arrays or TV cells is pertinent).  FWIW when I've had similar errors before it's due to timing between the various inserts/deletes/reloads.

Comment: Hey @flanker, the problem is I have no clue what is causing the crash. I am not even able to replicate this reliably on my end, but several users reported it and I see the crash keeps coming up in the crash logs. If I had to take a guess, I think forming the arrays is actually a part of the issue, because a task moves from one filtered array to another and something goes wrong with the count of items before and after. But I could be wrong..

Comment: Sorry to say that the code you provide is quite messy and difficult to reproduce with so many unclear variables. May I ask what Storage is or how it works? The error you faced is literally as described, it happened when the UITableView found that the numberOfRowInSection (from dataSource) has a mismatch after you drag the row (the presented UI). Could you please check if there is any delay / unexpected result in your dataSource (zone) after you drag the row?

Comment: Lets say we try to move row from sectionA = [A1, A2] to sectionB = [B1, B2, B3] inside tableView(tableView:moveRowAt:). When you drag the row A2 to under B3, the UI is expecting a data source [A1] & [B1, B2, B3, A2], but if the arrays are not updated appropriately, the apps will crash with the NSInternalInconsistencyException telling you that there is a mismatch in the no. of row in section (between dataSource & UI). (Instestingly you can try moving row in same section and no exception will happen, the UI is updated but the dataSource does not.)

Comment: The above is just the best guess I can give based on the provided code, and it would be nice if you could provide something more. I can provide my testing code if you want, but it seems meaningless coz I cannot reproduce the part of how you update your data source.

Comment: @paky Not crashing when moving code in the same section is consistent with the cause we are all suggesting - when moved in the same section the number of rows for a section doesn't change, and therefore isn't out of synch with the inserts/deletes, which is what is causing the crash.

Comment: @flanker Therefore I was asking for more information, as for now we could only guess there is a delay / unexpected result (something like the dataSource is not updated yet after task?.save()), but can't really tell because we have no idea how task?.save() or Storage work. Sorry that maybe I made my sentence too long.

Comment: Hey @paky and thank you for your replies. Storage is a class that handles UserDefault storage. It contains one array of Zone, and a Zone holds several these tasks that are moved. Here's what I mean: https://pastebin.com/cWWRf2ca task?.save() looks like this: https://pastebin.com/ZDueuXC9 It's a little messy and I imagine pretty inefficient but what it does is find the zone that contains this task and the index of the task in this zone by UUID and then update it in UserDefaults.

Comment: I was only able to replicate the issue on my end with two tasks and adding a 0.2s delay to reloadTableView() after reading the zone from UserDefaults stopped the issue on my end, but the user who experienced it reported it didn't solve it for him and I am not able to replicate it again. Do you think it's because saving the task with the way I'm doing it and then reading from UserDefaults takes a long time and the tableView tries to reload before that? I reached out to Apple for code level support also and they suggested I stop using UserDefaults altogether and load the CK data into memory.

Comment: How many items are you putting into UserDefaults.  Sounds like you're using it as a document/data store which is beyond it's design scope somewhat.

Comment: Adding delay to reloadTableView() is really not a good idea to fix these kinds of problem, because you never know the actual loading time. And as @Dad's answer , using UserDefault to store items like this is probably not ideal, JSON file is probably the best suit for this case, and you can try CoreData if you have a more complex relationship between data. And it' nice to see that you got the correct answer, "3. and 4. don't complete in time before 5." ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the model object from which the tableview is getting data in response to the UI changes and then reload the table.
Currently it seems like you're changing `Storage.zones` but then you queue asynchronously the update from that to the view `zone` copy of the data model that is used to render the table view.  They are out of sync for a period of time (at least one cycle of the runloop) and that's likely when you are crashing.

You say you're updating the disk and then reading it back in but I don't see the code that reads it back in or see the code that obviously calls that code.  So it's unclear how sensitive that will be to device load etc. and thus how likely you are to hit this delay that causes the issue.

Aside:  If you have more than a few items, using UserDefaults to store this is probably not ideal.

Unless the list of items is really small, calling filter and sorting during `numberOfRowsInSection` is less than ideal (it's called pretty often).  As long as you're caching zones you might as well cache the organized data into the sub-lists your filters are returning?
Anyway, that's probably not the root cause of your crash.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Reading the data from UserDefaults is handled by the Storage class. Here's what the zones variable looks like there: https://pastebin.com/cWWRf2ca

So the order in which events are executed is this:
1. The user drops a task from one index to another.
2. The dueDate of the task is changed based on the section it is dropped in
3. task.save() is called, which rewrites all zones and all tasks to disk - https://pastebin.com/ZDueuXC9
4. zone = Storage.zones[zoneIndex] will load the latest version of the zone into the vc's memory
5. tableView.reloadData()

Comment: So like others said, what you're suggesting is that operations 3. and 4. don't complete in time before 5. is called and that's what causes the crash? What is the alternative though? I could ditch UserDefaults and have CK load its data straight into memory. If I understood this correctly, this is what Apple suggested via a code level support request.

Comment: Yah too much going on between the table telling the datasource to move the rows and the actual in-memory model of the data getting updated to match what the table thinks it is.  Not surprised they're getting out of sync and causing the table to assert that it's inconsistent.  As I said above, change the in-memory data model immediately (before sending out notifications and all that other stuff).  Then save it to disk asynchronously as you have it set up.

Comment: What's all this doing?         Push.updateAllReminders()       Push.updateBadge()
         WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()

Comment: Ah, that sounds like a simpler solution. I will consider dropping UserDefaults also, but for now I think updating the version in memory directly and handling UserDefaults separately after is the way to go.

Comment: Yep. I'd start there.  And yah UserDefaults is probably not the best place to store this on disk.

Comment: Push is a class responsible for local notifications, so it will update reminders after a task's due date was edited (drag and drop is to move a task from today to tomorrow for example) and update the red badge on the app. WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines() reloads all the widgets, which can for example display tasks for today only so now they need to be reloaded.

Comment: Yah, don't do anything extraneous during the move delegate call.  Just update the data model and return.  Queue other stuff (notifications, saving to disk) to later.

Comment: Can I ask for clarification on two things? When you say queue the other operations, what do you mean? Background Queue? Also, I know UserDefaults isn't ideal, but what would you use for this? CoreData? I realise now I don't even need a local cache for the app, just for the widgets (which need an app group).

Comment: Sure. You currently do an async to the main thread for the save and that's a fine way to do it later in this case.

Comment: It looks like it's just json?  So why not save it to a JSON text file on disk?  I don't see any need to get fancy - it's just a local cache.  Have an in-memory copy in the app.  Unless the size of it is large enough you need to be able to load parts of it at a time, but I don't see your code treating it piecemeal like that so that seems unnecessary.

Comment: Got it, thanks again for the answer and tips.

Comment: Sure.  This was a pretty complicated long piece of code for an SO question, but I think this is the root cause issue and hopefully you'll be able to clean it up and move on to more exciting things than pulling your hair out over a hard to reproduce bug! :)